# How to place the fab button on the edge of a div?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, floating-action-button

On the top of the page, I’ve got a div for which background image has been set. I want to place the fab button on the bottom right edge of this div. Exactly like the following image. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Using the `edge` attribute with FAB doesn't worked for you? https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#fabs

Comment: @GabrielBarreto No it only place the FAB on the bottom or top edge of the screen.

Comment: Post your code so we can take a look

Answer (score 7):

Just use the `edge` attribute that comes along with [fabs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#fabs):

```
<ion-fab bottom right edge>
  <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon></button>
</ion-fab>
```

For this to work the `div` (or any tag) having the fab inside must have `position` set to `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` to work, `position: inherit` may work too depending on parent positioning.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Garrett and @Gabriel, I got it working using the following markup and scss. It's important to place the FAB button inside the div to which we want to assign the background image so that we can use `relative` positioning:

```
<ion-content>

  <div id="header">
    <ion-fab bottom right edge>
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-fab>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

And the `scss` file:

```
#header {
  background-image: url('../assets/images/anonymous.jpg')!important;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 25vh;
}

ion-fab {
  position: relative;
}

ion-fab[bottom][edge] {
  bottom: -21vh;
}

.fab {
  margin-right: 3vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I could get to work.
This works by creating a fab-container that is going to overlay the main container on this page. For this to work you need to know their heights. Then we make the fab-container z-index of 1 to be on top. Then we can use flex to make the fab be in the bottom right. Then we can add a margin-top half the size of the fab to the fab-container to have the fab hover halfway in-between. Lastly we can add margin-right to get the fab off the right side.

This may not be the best way to do it, since it requires knowing the height of your container, but it was the way that I would approach this task.

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="fab-conatainer">
        <ion-fab class="fab">
            <button ion-fab>
                <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-fab>
    </div>
    <div class="contacts-container">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-input placeholder="Name"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-input placeholder="Phone"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-input placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
       </ion-list>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

CSS

```
  .container {
   width: 100%;
   background: #333;
   height: 500px;
 }

 .fab-conatainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 28px;
 }

 .fab {
  margin-right: 14px;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, please take a look at my answer.